# Extracting variable name from file name

Tags: python, string, for-loop, variable-assignment, filenames

I am trying to extract variable names from file names as follows:

```
happy = "LOL"
angry = "GRRRR"
surprised= "YUPPIE"
file_names=["happy.wav","angry.wav","surprised.wav"

for i in file_names:
  name = i.split('.')
  name_=name[0]
  print(name_)
```

I get the output as:

```
happy
angry
surprised
```

when I wish to get the output as:

```
"LOL"
"GRRRR"
"YUPPIE"
```

What is my code missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use a dict, not individual variables, when the variable names should be treated as data.

```
d = {"happy": "LOL", "angry": "GRRRR", "surprised": "YUPPIE"}
for i in file_names:
    name = i.split(".")[0]
    print(d[name])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going about this the wrong way. What if the file_names has more file names tomorrow? Would you create more variables? That would be poor design.

What you need is a dictionary. Something like this:

```
dictionaryOfFileNames = {"happy": "LOL", "angry": "GRRRR", "surprised": "YUPPIE"}
file_names=["happy.wav","angry.wav","surprised.wav"]

for i in file_names:
    name = i.split('.')
    name_=name[0]
    print(dictionaryOfFileNames.get(name_))
```

In this case, if the name does not exist, you will get a `None`.